# Routing errors with expressjs and object constructors

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, coffeescript

Im creating an API REST with express and nodejs and im on the early phase of my routing.

My idea is create "controllers" for every route separated and call that controller in a router file, something like:

```
...
router.post('/login', loginCtrl.login(req, res));
```

In other project i handled that with a simple object of functions, requiring it and then just calling that functions. Now my idea is something more interesting, im working with the object constructor, like:

```
var ctrl = function() {
   this.login = function(req, res) {
     res.json({ msg: 'hello' }); // just an example
   }
}
```

Im writing this on coffeescript (the client wants coffee, so...) and the sintax is with that metalanguage but at least is identic, my problem is with `req` and `res`, this is my router file:

```
express = require 'express'
router = express.Router()

###
  Rutas de autenticación
###
AuthController = require '../controllers/authenticate'
auth = new AuthController()

router.post '/setup'   , auth.setup req, res
router.post '/register', auth.register req, res
router.post '/login'   , auth.login req, res

module.exports = router
```

When the server runs, it throws me this error:

```
/home/nano/Dev/erp-api/app/routes/apiroutes.coffee:17
  router.post('/setup', auth.setup(req, res));
                                   ^
ReferenceError: req is not defined
```

Exactly why this happens? I have no idea, it works when i worked with plain objects.

Answer (score 0):

Like you did you are calling the function setup with the variables, while what you want is to pass the reference to the function. so you have to just pass the reference to it and not executing it.

```
router.post '/setup'   , auth.setup
```

req, res will automatically be passed to that function.